# Mini-map of HTML page sections shown as fixed anchors in viewport

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, layout

I saw a site a month or two ago that had anchors fixed to the right side of the page that would not scroll when the page was scrolled. That alone is not hard to do with CSS.

But on that site, the fixed anchors were dynamically generated based on the section headers in the page. And they were proportionately spaced down the right side of the page in relation to their position in the document.

In essence, it created a mini-map of the entire document, giving a visual overview of what was in the document, and the spacing between sections of the document, all within the current viewport. You could quickly see how large each section was in relation to each other. Maybe I should call it a table-of-contents instead of a mini-map.

I believe this was on a documentation page for an API of some sort. I think it worked really well for navigation, and want to build something like it for some documentation I need to do.

In a way, it reminded me of the minimap on the right side of Sublime Text 2, but only major headings were shown and they were depicted as buttons fixed to the right side of the page.
[image: sublime text 2 minimap]

Unfortunately, I can't remember or find the site I saw it on. Has anyone seen an example of something like this? I'd love to see some examples before I start implementing it. Or do any tools exist for doing this, jquery plugins, etc?